# Why does HTML Canvas rounded lineCap fail for last segment?

Tags: html, canvas

With the HTML Canvas if you draw a dotted line like this:

```
ctx.lineWidth   = 40;
ctx.lineCap     = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(150,200);
ctx.moveTo(200,300);
ctx.lineTo(250,400);
ctx.moveTo(300,500);
ctx.lineTo(350,600);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

then the result is this:

[image: Dashed line with first two dashes using rounded line caps and last dash using butt caps]
<sub>(source: [phrogz.net](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_broken_rounded_stroke.png))</sub>

As you can see on [this test page](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_broken_rounded_stroke.html), adding a "superfluous" `moveTo` call after the last `lineTo` fixes the last line segment to use rounded caps.

I was prepared to file this as a bug, but then I found that the behavior is identical on Safari v5, Chrome v8, and FireFox v3.6 and v4.0b. This leads me to believe that it is intentional.

**Where in the standard is this behavior specified, and (if you can discern it) why was it specced as such?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the relevant definitions from the [canvas spec (section 9, paths)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#complex-shapes-paths):

> The `moveTo(x, y)` method must create a new subpath with the specified point as its first (and only) point.
>
> The `lineTo(x, y)` method ... must connect the last point in the subpath to the given point (x, y) using a straight line, and must then add the given point (x, y) to the subpath.
>
> The `closePath()` method ... must mark the last subpath as closed ... this is equivalent to adding a straight line connecting the last point back to the first point, thus "closing" the shape ...

Each `moveTo` call creates a new subpath, thus ending the previous subpath. In your case, the first two segments are ended this way. For the final segment, calling `closePath` "closes" the segment by drawing another segment in the reverse direction, hence the result you are seeing -- there is not one segment but rather two overlapping segments. Adding another `moveTo` ends this segment just like the others, so you see the rounded line cap as expected.

Comment: In other words: while you should always call `beginPath()` when starting your new path, you only should call `closePath()` when you actually need it and know what it does. It's not required, or desired, most of the time.